# Responsive full page background image with CSS

Tags: css, background

I am trying to achieve full length responsive background image as done in this website http://www.dubsmash.com/ 
I tried applying `background-size: cover; background:url('image') no-repeat center center; overflow:hidden; min-height:100%` to html
but the result is different.

See the way how image is centered at all times in the dubsmash website. They used jquery to dynamically calculate height, width and left, top properties for image inside the wrapping div on `window.resize`

My question is can some one help me in understanding how they are calculating width, top and left to the `img`

**Update**:

My Code So far:
HTML:

```
<div class="bgHome" style="position:fixed;z-index:-1;top:0;left:0;overflow:hidden">
        <img src="http://www.dubsmash.com/wp-content/themes/dubsmash2.0/pics/woman.jpg" style="position:absolute;top:0"/>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready (function(){
    checkDims();
});

$(window).resize(checkDims);

function checkDims(){
    a = $(window).height();
    b = $(window).width();  
    $('.bgHome').css({"height":a,"width":b});
    $('.bgHome img').css({"height":a,"width":b});

}
```

**Update -2**:

```
<html></html>
```

Css:

```
html{
     background-size:100%;top:0; left:0;
     background:url('http://www.dubsmash.com/wp-content/themes/dubsmash2.0/pics/woman.jpg') no-repeat center center;
     overflow:hidden;width:100%;height:100%
}
```

Comment: Do you need parallax effect? Do you also want that your bg image moves on scroll?

Comment: I am not looking for parallax effect and no scroll. I am just wondering if I can use similar concept in setting up a background image

Comment: Yes you can, do you want very first image to take for example?

Comment: they are also changing backgound-position

Comment: @Scott, I dont see background position property to either div or img tag

Comment: First of all it is not a background image, it's DOM element, so concept changes from beginning.

Comment: Updated my question with code. Please find the code I am using for my page. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

their HTML looks like:

```
<section class="module parallax" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="http://www.dubsmash.com/wp-content/themes/dubsmash2.0/pics/man_singing.jpg">
</section>
```

their CSS ( or some of it ):

```
padding: 240px 0;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
/* background-attachment: fixed; */
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
```

then there is a bunch of javascript to handle that parallax

i would suggest setting the background-image of `bgHome` not having an `<img>` as a child , and then in css set this:

```
.bgHome{
    backgound-image: url('put-url-here');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: I see different html elements. There are 4 div tags immediately within the body tag. First image html is in the 4th div tag.

Comment: no , the the image is in a section tag if you look closer , I thought the same thing at first .  Anyways - I'm pretty sure just setting background-position: center will get you the effect you wanted

Comment: So Scott, for my above code, where do you suggest adding background property. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try out this solution and adjust it. For some reason I can't paste link so you'll get this ugly one :D

```
    Get it below
```

[Codepen sample](http://codepen.io/zlajaa1/pen/LVNMRj)

Comment: paste your code here , you can use a link as well to demo , but don't just post a link

Comment: Can't paste code either :( formated wrong, but I can't find a mistake.

Comment: Oh yeah, it will work on resize, so make sure you drag it around to get started

Comment: Trid that @Zlatko. But the same effect can be achieved by using background-size:cover for html instead of going through jquery.

Comment: Difference is in css Cover property. Try 100% for bg-size, and explain me what do you need here, the way it act on example website is controlled by plugin I suppose.